# why compiler kotlin with error message Conflicting overloads problem

Tags: kotlin

I am a beginner in Kotlin. I have a kt file that no class function name "test1" which is the same as the class name.
android studio compiler display error message.

**Kotlin: Conflicting overloads: public constructor test1() defined in com.demo.test1, public fun test1(): Unit defined in com.demo.**

Why can’t class name and function name be the same?
they are essentially different in nature,
or how to correct them?

test1.kt

```
package com.demo

class test1() {
    init { 
        println("First initializer ");
    }
}
```

main.kt

```
package com.demo

fun test1() {
    var s1: String? = "10.25"
    println(s1) 
}

fun main(argus: Array<String>) {
    test1();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically says that you have two functions with the same definition in the current context: `test1()` and the constructor of the `test1` class.

To solve this problem you can rename your class into `Test1` (capital t). This is also one of the general programming rules: class names must start with a capital letter and should follow the PascalCase type https://www.chaseadams.io/posts/most-common-programming-case-types/#camelcase

In the Kotlin documentation you also have a coding conventions guide: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html